# Jquery with fadein

Tags: jquery, fadein

My code is a form validation if not filled in than display the X error using jquery it works fine but i want to add when the error shows i want it in a fade in style. Thanks.

```
function error1(act,txt1){
    hideshow1('error1',act);
    if(txt1) $('#error1').fadeIn('slow', function(txt1){

        $(this).html();

    });
}
```

Comment: what is this code? pls be more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
function error1(act, txt1)
{
    hideshow1('error1', act);
    if (txt1)
    {
        $('#error1').html(txt1).fadeIn('slow');
    }

}
```

Comment: Working Thanks man ... WOOW so simple and wasnt even thinking